# Minimize this functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, calculus-of-variations

Given the functional $F:H^1(0,1)\cap \left\{f(0)=a, f(1)=b\right\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

such that $$F(g):= \int_0^1 g(x)f(x)dx.$$

where $f$ is a fixed $H^1$-function. I would like to find an upper bound for the minimizer of this function in $H^1$-norm such that $F(g)=c$ where $a,b,c$ are fixed real constants.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: You would like to find an upper bound for all $g$ that satisfy $F(g) = \min_{h\in \operatorname{dom}F} F(h)$? I am pretty sure that $F$ doesn't have a minimum and $\inf_{g\in \operatorname{dom}F} F(g) = -\infty$ if $f$ isn't constant $0$.

Comment: no, I am solving $k:=\inf_{g \in \operatorname{dom}(F)} \left\lVert g \right\rVert_{H^1}$ such that $F(g)=c. $ I would like to have an upper bound on $k$. But thank you for asking, this may have been a bit unclear from my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually find the minimizer using Lagrange multipliers (in the infinite dimensional case) [Lagrange for Banach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multipliers_on_Banach_spaces). 
Miniminizing $\Vert g\Vert_{H^1}$ is the same as minimizing $\Vert g\Vert_{H^1}^2$, so using Lagrange multipliers, you are finding critical points of
$$ H(g)=\Vert g\Vert_{H^1}^2+\lambda \left(\int_0^1 fg\,dx-c\right).$$
If you differentiate, that is, given $h\in H^1_0$ you consider the derivative of the function of one variable $p(t)=H(g+th)$, you find
$$0=p'(0)=\int_0^1(2g'h'+2gh+\lambda fh)\,dx.$$
If $g$ is smooth, then you can integrate by parts to get
$$0=\int_0^1(-2g''+2g+\lambda f)h\,dx.$$
Since this is true for all $h$ you find that
$$-2g''+2g+\lambda f=0.$$
This is a linear differential equation. You can solve this using variations of parameters (see here [second order ode](http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-2nd%20order%20ODE%20pt1.pdf))